# Read telegram group message

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I am into one telegram group. I wanted to read those messages in my python code. Is there any way to read those messages without adding bot in that group.. for example abc is my user id... And abc is added in xyz group. So wanted to read xyz group message in my python code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that via using Telegram API named Telethon.

[Telethon Github](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon)

Here is an example for setting up processes of the Telethon API. I've written this code to pull all newly posted images from one telegram group. It will give you an idea of how to start to use it.

```
import sys
import os

from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetFullChatRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetChannelsRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser, PeerChat, PeerChannel
import re
# These example values won't work. You must get your own api_id and
# api_hash from https://my.telegram.org, under API Development.
api_id = 11111  #number
api_hash = 'x'#string
phone = 'x'
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash,update_workers=1, spawn_read_thread=False)
client.connect()
```

Also if you are interested in all of my code on this Telethon integration, you can find it in the following GitHub link;

[Telegram Group Bot](https://github.com/ozanyurtsever/telegrampumpgroup-bot/blob/master/image.py)

Comment: Ok thanks any code snippet will help me .. kinda newbie in telegram stuff

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this thread : [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56295761/how-to-get-message-from-telegram-groups-by-api-python)

I found this code really works for me. Note that this is a synchronous function, if you want to use multiple channels at the same time you may need to make use of asyncio. Detailed information about that in the next link --> [Async Quick-Start](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/quick-start.html)

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync

api_id = ...
api_hash = '...'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='channel_name'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

For the code above, you have to replace "channel_name" with the name of the group your user is on.
api_id and api_hash are obtained when you setup your API app in Telegram.