# How to get a message from Telegram groups by API?

Tags: python, api, chat, telegram

I was looking for some way to listen and catch new messages provided by telegram groups.

I have not found libraries or API in order to do this in Python.

Someone having any suggestion?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve your goal:

## Method 1:

#### My suggested library for python: [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)

1. Create a bot.
2. Add the bot to the desired group as administrator.
3. Listen to messages as you normally listen in bots.

## Method 2:

#### My suggested library for python: [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon)

1. Join the desired group as a user (not a bot).
2. Create a simple client that listens to new messages.

Comment: Add the bot to the desired group as administrator. What if group isn't own by us?

Comment: @Gentleman turn off privacy setting from the bot and it should listen to messages normally.

Comment: dude i have an issue to read the content protected channel and i can't grab the text of post , i don't know how to solve it ...

Answer (score 26):

**Using Telethon**

Replace `channel_name` with your telegram channel.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync

# Remember to use your own values from my.telegram.org!
api_id = ...
api_hash = '...'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='channel_name'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Can you please provide the specific question you are asking, or where you are getting stuck?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. This is an example of how using Telethon I can listen and catch new message of a specific group.

Comment: How to bypass this - Please enter your phone (or bot token):

Comment: I am unable to use this approach to access multiple groups. Say if I want to receive messages from multiple groups or channels.

Comment: Add the bot to the desired group as administrator.