# View filtered real time updates of this channel using python

Tags: python, telethon

I am a part of a public telegram channel with too much noise and only some meaningful important updates. I want to filter out noise and need to view real time updates(new messages) with specific words in text body of message of this channel using  python.

I followed the code from below post by Lonami to try and get messages and it works beautifully, but it brings in all the historical messages as well.

[Telegram get chat messages /posts - python Telethon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50975793/telegram-get-chat-messages-posts-python-telethon)

Could someone guide me to get the new messages real time one by one as they are posted ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read [help/on-topic] and [ask] for tips on how to improve your question so that it attracts the answers you are looking for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56295761/how-to-get-message-from-telegram-groups-by-api-python You can follow this question and just do a simple ```if your_wanted_word in message:``` statement to see if the new message meets your requirements...

Comment: Hi @Andrej  - thanks a lot this works well. the issue observed now is this code only retrieves new messages at set intervals- for instance i tried today and depending on the script execution time it only returns information at HH:MM:56 instead of realtime- can we reduce the polling period checking new messages for events.NewMessage ? i looked up but couldnt find much - also please answer this question so i can mark your answer as helpful instead of comment :)

Comment: You can try using a ```while True:``` loop. And running the code inside of it.

Comment: i tried but it got stuck in While true loop insteading of now sending any update at all:

here is my code - can you show me how ?


client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='CHANNELNAME'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print("Current Time = ", current_time)
    print(event.raw_text)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()

Comment: Put your code in function, let's call it main. And then ```while True: sleep(5) # Gets new messages every 5 seconds main()```